# pick interpolation -- why is it symmetric? $\left[\frac{1 - w_i \overline{w_j}}{1 - z_i \overline{z_j}} \right]_{i,j=1}^n \geq 0$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, operator-theory

I am reading [notes](http://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/advanced-analysis-notes-17-hilbert-function-spaces-picks-interpolation-theorem/) on a complex interpolation problem:

> Let $z_1, \dots, z_n \in \mathbb{D}$ and $w_1, \dots, w_n \in \mathbb{C}$. There exists (bounded holomorphic?) $f \in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ with $||f||_\infty \leq 1$ taking $$ f: z_1 \mapsto w_1 \; \dots \; z_n \mapsto w_n$$
>   If and only if the following matrix inequality holds: $$ \left[\frac{1 - w_i \overline{w_j}}{1 - z_i \overline{z_j}} \right]_{i,j=1}^n \geq 0 $$

I am not a complex analyst, but I have been examining interpolation problems of this kind.  Here is the caricature I currently have for this result:

> Let $z_1, \dots, z_n \in \mathbb{D}$ and $w_1, \dots, w_n \in \mathbb{C}$. There exists  holomorphic $f \in H^2(\mathbb{D})$ taking $$ f: z_1 \mapsto w_1 \; \dots \; z_n \mapsto w_n$$
>   If and only if the the matrix is positive definite: $$ \left[\frac{1 - w_i \overline{w_j}}{1 - z_i \overline{z_j}} \right]_{i,j=1}^n \geq 0 $$

And it may in fact be false when stated this way.  That's issue #1.

---

I know that the function $ \frac{1}{1 - z \overline{z}}$ is the reproducing kernel for the Hardy space $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ -- the [Szego kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szeg%C5%91_kernel).  I could imagine trying to solve the system of equations:

$$ \begin{array}[ccccc]
 ff(z) &=& a_0 + a_1 z + \dots + a_n z^n + \dots &=& w \\
&\dots & \\
f(z) &=& a_0 + a_1 z + \dots + a_n z^n + \dots &=& w 
 \end{array}$$

and hopefully this matrix occurs somehow.  Instead of generalizing to other kernels, I would like to know why this condition is symmetric in $z$ and $w$, especially since $f(z)$ is not generally invertible but should have many branch points.

And I don't really understand why positive-definiteness and boundedness are equivalent in the first place.

Comment: Could you explain why the Pick condition "is symmetric in z and w"?

Comment: the numerator and denominator have the same form.

Comment: The first box is correct, the second one is trivially false as stated ($z=0$, $w=1234$), maybe you meant something else really. This is a very classical topic, I suspect a look into Garnett's book (say) will answer most of your questions.

Comment: Also, as already suggested by the formulae, Blaschke products play a prominent role here, not polynomials.

Comment: @johnmangual Sure, but I would usually interpret "Condition X is symmetric in z and w" to mean "(z,w) satisfies Condition X if and only if (w,z) does". The operation "entrywise reciprocal" doesn't preserve the property of being positive (semi-)definite.

Comment: Re: your final question/comment: if you can get access to a copy, Agler and McCarthy's book http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Pick_Interpolation_and_Hilbert_Function.html?id=qx5VsaD589gC has a good explanation/proof

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks for the book reference - it has Chapter 1 in full.  I am afraid you are right... taking reciprocals of the entries will not preserve positive definiteness.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I am confused by your counterexample.  Will look into the Garnett book.  That Pick interpolation is well understood should work to my advantage... since I was motivated by a paper from 2003

Comment: @johnmangual: Oh, all I'm saying is $f\equiv c$ is in $H^2$, but the condition won't hold for $z=0$, $w=c$ if $|c|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your "caricature" is trivially true without any condition of positivity.
(That is when you remove the second sentence it becomes true). Just take
the interolation polynomial. Polynomials are evidently in $H^2$. And also in $H^\infty$.
The main condition in the Pick theorem for which positivity is needed is the
condition that $\| f\|_\infty\leq 1$.

Comment: right.  [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) gives us at least one polynomial for any collections of $z_1, \dots, z_n$ and $w_1, \dots, w_n$.

Comment: So what is your question, then?